# Azure Fileshare - Using Docker-Compose to Mount Different Subfolders/Files to volume on ACI

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, azure-container-instances, azure-files

I have different services on the `docker-compose` file that pulls some images to create containers on ACI.
Everything works fine on my local machine when I mount different directories and sub folders to docker containers:

```
volumes:
 - folder/sub_folder/sub/folder:/etc/nginx/certs
```

But spinning up instances on ACI requires using `azure_file` driver which I use but I am not able to mount subfolders from this fileshare to a path.

I created a volume in the compose file:

```
  volumes:
      data-volume:
        driver: azure_file
        driver_opts:
          share_name: acishare
          storage_account_name: storageaccount
          storage_account_key: /run/secrets/storage_account_key.txt
```

and I have tried this for a container

```
  services:
   app:  
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/etc/nginx/
```

The above works fine but mounts the home directory of the file share which is understandable since no directory was specified.

I did some research and saw that on AKS, one could specify the directory of the file as the share name. Tried this with the backward slash() but I got an error message saying the fileshare doesn't exist:

```
volumes:
  data-volume:
    driver: azure_file
    driver_opts:
      share_name: acishare/sub_directory/sub_directory
      storage_account_name: storageaccount
      storage_account_key: /run/secrets/storage_account_key.txt
```

I have also tried adding the path to the volume but this won't work too:

```
volumes:
  - data-volume/sub_directory/sub_directory:/etc/nginx/
```

What is the correct way to mount different subfolders of Azure File Share to an ACI?

PS: My codebase is on github and I am using workflow to `upload-batch` files to the azure file share because I need to copy (mount) a subfolder to the wwwroot directory in the container.
The repo also has some configuration files that need to be directly mounted to the container. These files are also not on the root folder but inside different subfolders.

If there is a better alternative to handle situations like this, I don't mind. I have tried using blob storage but couldn't come up with a way to go about it.

Comment: Did you solve this? I am also interested in mounting an Azure file share subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try this:

```
volumeMounts:
    -  mountPath: /main/path
       subPath: data
       name: whatevername
```

Check the following link I hope it helps.
[azure subdirs](https://github.com/Azure/ACS/issues/119)

Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

I tried to reproduce but unable mount a single file/folder from Azure File Share to Azure Container Instance.

**Deploy container and mount volume**

```
    az container create \
    --resource-group $ACI_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP \
    --name hellofiles \
    --image mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/aci-hellofiles \
    --dns-name-label aci-demo \
    --ports 80 \
    --azure-file-volume-account-name $ACI_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME \
    --azure-file-volume-account-key $STORAGE_KEY \
    --azure-file-volume-share-name $ACI_PERS_SHARE_NAME \
    --azure-file-volume-mount-path /aci/logs/
```

.

```
 STORAGE_KEY=$(az storage account keys list --resource-group $ACI_PERS_RESOURCE_GROUP --account-name $ACI_PERS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME --query "[0].value" --output tsv)
    echo $STORAGE_KEY
```

[image]

[image]

Here one more thing notice whatever the files you will update in file share it will update in container as well after you mount the file share as volume to the container.
May this be the reason we can not mount specific file and folder as volume in container.

[image]

**There are some limitations to this as well,**

•   You can only mount Azure Files shares to Linux containers. Review more about the differences in feature support for Linux and Windows container groups in the overview.

•   You can only mount the whole share and not the subfolders within it.

•   Azure file share volume mount requires the Linux container run as root.

•   Azure File share volume mounts are limited to CIFS support.

•   Share cannot be mounted as read-only.

•   You can mount multiple volumes but not with Azure CLI and would have to use ARM templates instead.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/mounting-azure-file-share-as-volumes-in-azure-containers-step-by-step-demo/